# How to see photos and delete the bad ones?

Tags: finder, photos

I have a folder with 200 photos and would like to delete the bad ones. I tried to sort them by Creation Date in the Finder and open with Quick Look:

[image: Screenshot of a folder with 84 jpg files selected and the contextual menu with Quick Look selected]

But when I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> all selected photos are moved to trash. How can I get the "Open All-See-Move to the next photo-Delete current photo-Move to the next photo" experience on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickLook can be activated by simply tapping the spacebar.

If you select the top item in the list, tap spacebar, then you can step up or down using the arrow keys.
This way, only one file is selected at a time. If you Cmd/Delete, then QuickLook will just jump to the next image.

Tap spacebar again when you've finished with QuickLook.

Comment: Tank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selecting all photos, just select the first one and press <kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger Quick Look.

- If you want to keep it, press "cursor down"
- If you want to delete it, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> which will delete the current photo and automatically display the next one